# HTTP Middleware and Google Cloud Functions

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, middleware

What’s the equivalent to middleware handlers in Google Cloud Functions?

In standard approach, normally I do:

```
router.Handle("/receive", middlewares.ErrorHandler(MyReceiveHandler))
```

And then, in the middleware:

```
type ErrorHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error

func (fn ErrorHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := fn(w, r) 
    if err == nil {
        return
    }
    log.Printf("An error accured: %v", err) 
    clientError, ok := err.(errors.BaseError) 
    if !ok {
        w.WriteHeader(500) 
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(clientError.GetStatusCode())
    w.Write([]byte(clientError.Error()))
}
```

In AWS Lambda, I can achieve the same thing using, for example:

```
func main() {
    lambda.Start(
        middlewares.Authentication(Handler),
    )
}
```

But I could not find a way to do this in GCP Functions.
How would it work?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you start with the following server code in your development environment:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", MiddlewareFinalMsg(" Goodbye!", http.HandlerFunc(HelloWorld)))
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func MiddlewareFinalMsg(msg string, h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        fmt.Fprint(w, msg)
    })
}

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
}
```

As far as I can tell, GCF requires its *entry point* to be an exported identifier of type `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` (not `http.HandlerFunc`, not `http.Handler`); therefore, if you have a `http.Handler`, you'll need to select its `ServeHTTP` method explicitly to obtain a function of the expected type. However, that identifier can be a package-level function, a method, or a variable.

Here is how you can adapt the code above for GCF:

```
package p

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

// use F as your GCF's entry point
var F = MiddlewareFinalMsg(" Goodbye!", http.HandlerFunc(HelloWorld)).ServeHTTP

func MiddlewareFinalMsg(msg string, h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        fmt.Fprint(w, msg)
    })
}

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
}
```

Comment: I don't think a got it.. could you show me a code example, please? sorry

Comment: Now I can understand clearly, though my function returns an error, since it is an error handling middleware (type ErrorHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error). Would it still be possible?

Comment: @thiago In your code snippet, what is the signature of `router.Handle`? Also, I fail to see what makes ErrorHandler a middleware. It doesn't take a handler and return a new handler...